# what xpath 1 expression to do case-insensitive matching of multiline text?

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

I have some html markup that contains many labels that look like this:

```
<label>One two three four</label>
<label>One two three<br>four</label>
```

I'm trying to access the elements in a selenium test, based on the text string "One two three four". I want to be able to match both of the above examples.

My first attempt at an xpath looks like this:

```
//label[text()[contains(., 'One two three four')]]
```

This works fine for labels that don't contain a `<br>` in the text, but fails to find the second instance that has a `<br>`.

Doing a little research, it seems like normalize-space should work, but it doesn't seem to. This is the xpath I tried, which returns only the first node

```
//label[text()[contains(normalize-space(.), 'One two three four')]]
```

I also tried this, but it returns zero nodes

```
//label[normalize-space(text())[contains(., 'Generate')]]
```

So, is there a way to craft an xpath that looks for a label with the text "One two three four", even if there is a `<br>` element in the actual html markup?

Comment: You can select `<label>One two three<br>four</label>` using `//label[. = 'One two threefour']` or `//label[contains(., 'One two threefour')]`. There is no text between `three` and `four` in that case.

Comment: @MartinHonnen: ugh. You're right. That explains why my attempts are failing, but it doesn't help me with my goal of being able to use "One two three four"  in the query to match both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or `translate()` away the spaces andthenmatchonthat:

```
$ cat foo.html 
<label>One two three four</label>
<label>One two three<br>four</label>
$ xpquery -p HTML '//label[contains(translate(normalize-space(.), " ", ""), "Onetwothreefour")]/text()' foo.html
One two three four
One two three
four
$
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That may be what I have to do -- normalize the labels to some standard (eg: all lowercase, no spaces) and search on that.